# Does continuous observation of an entangled particle keep it locked in its current state?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

If two particles are entangled, and one of the particles ParticleA is periodically polled or pulsed of for it's state, and the other particle ParticleB is polled for a duration in seconds, will the duration polling of ParticleB lock ParticleA in its current state, so that when observed with pulses over that same period of time, it will guarantee the same state is observed?

Basically I'm wondering if entanglement can be used as a beacon. If one of the pair is rapidly checking to detect if it's entangled twin is being observed over a duration. Sort of like, if I flip the coin 1000 times, and it lands on heads 1000 times in a row, then I know the entangled twin coin is being observed.

Does that make sense?

Comment: If you measure one particle, you destroy the entanglement.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch thanks Norbert. Also I got pointed toward the zeno effect. I think I have an understanding now. You can lock a particle by observing it, but regardless you lose the entangled property. This now makes me wonder how a quantum processor could ever work if you're never allowed to observe the outcome. Hrmm..

Comment: @AndrewHoffman You do observe the outcome to get a result from a quantum processor, and yes that may/will destroy the entanglement. There is no problem with that. Actually it is often useful to think of entanglement as like a resource which you "burn" as fuel to do the computation.

Comment: @AndrewHoffman as Norbert Schuch sais, once you tested particle A, you collapsed the particle B on the corresponding state, and whatever you measure next on particle A, the particle B won't be anymore influenced. So, the answer is "no".

Answer (score 1):

If you do a strong measurement of a particle in an entangled pair, then they are no longer entangled, they get the correlation they have and thereafter you can measure or affect one without affecting the other (except to the degree that they interact).

If you want to do weak measurements you might get a different story.

In either case, you can (if you choose to) actually describe the actual experimental setup and evolve it according to the actual Schrödinger equation for the actual interaction. No one ever forces you to use words like measurement (either strong or weak), well maybe your instructor if you are a student or your boss if you are an employee, but you could still say no and do what the laws of physics tell you instead.

If you start to do an interaction that is like a measurement in the sense that it has states that are sent to themselves, you might start to reproduce the quantum Zeno effect if you interact too often.  This just means the evolution based on the interaction starts to be different than the evolution without the interaction, and specifically the evolution with the interaction might  get it stuck close to an eigenstate of the interaction instead of an eigenstate of non-interaction Hamiltonian.

An entangled state is just that, a state.  You can evolve from an entangled state into a non entangled state and vice versa and being entangled is not an interaction.  They don't exert special interactions with each other because they are in an entangled state and you can't use measurement to exploit the non existent special interaction.

That said there are states such that the so called probability current of the sum is not the sum of the so called probability currents of the individual states. And an entangled state does have the special characteristic that when you try to interact with one of the particles you have to also interact with the entangled particle in a particularly correlated way.  But that is just because the original state is entangled to have them correlated.  When you do a measurement, what you are doing is splitting a state into it's projections onto eigenvectors and since the original vector was already correlated to the other particle you get the split versions to be correlated too.  It is not a special interaction.